# How to handle multiple mathquill elements in single page

Tags: javascript, mathquill

I need to handle multiple mathquill input boxes at the same time in single page application. I didnt able to found any implementation of this also. So, is it possible to use multiple mathquill elements and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it downloading the following plugin

https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Simple-WYSIWYG-Math-Editor-With-jQuery-Mathquill-matheditor-js.html

and following these steps:

1) include scripts and css

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mathquill.min.js"></script>
<script src="/matheditor.js"></script>

<link href="mathquill.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="matheditor.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2) include multiple mathquill

```
<body>
 <div id="demo1"></div>
 <div id="demo2"></div>
 <div id="demo3"></div>
 <div id="demo4"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var demo1 = new MathEditor('demo1');
  var demo2 = new MathEditor('demo2');
  var demo3 = new MathEditor('demo3');
  var demo4 = new MathEditor('demo4');
</script>
</body>
```